# Building Soaprequest in iPhone

Tags: iphone, soap, request

So my problem is that i need to build large soap request, with multiple objects. My request depends on user input, that means that sometimes he can add even 10 complex objects into it. So building a string seams a bit hard. Is there any other way to do that? I was building same thing with android and there was a simple way of adding objects into request.

I know it's not to hard to build a string but why wouldn't there be more user friendly solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams that only way to do that is building a full string. After some trieing i found out that it's quite easy...

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest using [SudzC](http://sudzc.com/) via going to the SOAP api of the website you are using and getting the WSDL of the API, this website will then create a Zip file of all the code you would require to implement the soap service into an Application. I have used this a few times and it usually saves a lot of time.

After implementation calls can be made using:

```
Service *mySoapService;
SoapRequest *request;

    mySoapService = [[Service alloc]init];
    mySoapService = [Service service];
    [mySoapService setDefaultHandler:self];


request =  [mySoapService LoginWithPostedDateEx1:self  action:@selector(handleFind:) Username:userName Password:passWord LoginDt:loginDateString LoggedIn:TRUE PostedDt:loginDateString DeviceCaps:@"iPhone 4"];
```

The website will make the files and methods required you just add the Folder, headers, make instance of service and then create requests.

In the long request above you can see that `LoginWithPostedDateEx1` is in fact the SOAP call you would of been constructing manually.

Comment: thanks for ur advice but that doesn/t seam to help me add for example 20 examples of person, i steal have to do it... Hm i will probablz just build string by my self :S